# How to use Excel to automate the mapping of information

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am quite new to Excel and I am dealing with an Excel file to automate the mapping of information.

For example, I have a code: BB012H252N. It has 10 positions (characters)

Each one or two characters has its own meaning and I would like to create a formula to map that in a table, which can be used for new SKU as well.

I want to use a formula to map the info and I am thinking of using substring or index and vlookup or xlookup to do it. But I wonder if there is any more efficient way to do so? And how to substring the code is also a bit difficult for me as a beginner.

Any advice is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

I need to fill in the following table to test the mapping formula:

| Item | BB012H252N | CLID1M001Y | CDID1L999Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product Line | Butter |  |  |
| Form | Blocks |  |  |
| Origin | USA |  |  |
| Process | Non Thermal |  |  |
| Chemicals | High |  |  |
| Weight | 25 kilos |  |  |
| Plant | Plant 2 |  |  |
| Further | No |  |  |

The code structure is like the tables below:

| Position 1 |  |
| --- | --- |
| C | Coal |
| B | Butter |
| P | Pig |

| Position 2 |  |
| --- | --- |
| L | Liquid |
| B | Blocks |
| C | Chips |
| D | Drops |

| Position 3/4 |  |
| --- | --- |
| 00 | China |
| 01 | USA |
| 02 | Japan |
| ID | Indonesia origin |
| I1 | Ivory Coast North origin |

| Position 5 |  |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Thermal |
| 2 | Non Thermal |

| Position 6 |  |
| --- | --- |
| L | Low |
| M | Medium |
| H | High |

| Position 7/8 |  |
| --- | --- |
| 00 | Package |
| 01-99 | Weight in kilos |

| Position 9 |  |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Plant 1 |
| 2 | Plant 2 |
| ... |  |
| 8 | Plant 8 |

| Position 10 |  |
| --- | --- |
| Y | Yes |
| N | No |

Comment: I would build using left(), mid() and right() to get characters or pairs of characters then vlookup() or index() with match()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following formula, assuming there is no **`Excel Constraints`** as per the tags posted.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     α, TEXT(MID(B1,{1;2;3;5;6;7;9;10},{1;1;2;1;1;2;1;1}),"00"),
     IFERROR(MAP(α,SEQUENCE(ROWS(α)),LAMBDA(x,y,VLOOKUP(x,
     TEXT(SWITCH(y,1,F2:G4,2,F7:G10,3,F13:G17,4,F20:G21,5,F24:G26,6,F29:G30,7,F33:G41,8,F44:G45),"00"),2,0))),α&" kilos"))
```

---

And you can one single dynamic array formula to spill for the whole array, using <kbd>MAKEARRAY( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     α, TEXT(MID(B1:D1,{1;2;3;5;6;7;9;10},{1;1;2;1;1;2;1;1}),"00"),
     MAKEARRAY(ROWS(α),COLUMNS(α),LAMBDA(φ,δ,IFERROR(VLOOKUP(INDEX(α,φ,δ), 
    TEXT(SWITCH(φ,1,F2:G4,2,F7:G10,3,F13:G17,4,F20:G21,5,F24:G26,6,F29:G30,7,F33:G41,8,F44:G45),"00"),2,0),INDEX(α,φ,δ)&" kilos"))))
```

---

As per OPs comments:

> *This is so cool! I will check it thoroughly. Thank you for your help.*
> *By the way, If I want to directly add position 9 (number 1 to 9) after*
> *'Plant', instead of lookup for it. How should I add that to the*
> *formula you provided? Thank you.*

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     α, TEXT(MID(B1:D1,{1;2;3;5;6;7;9;10},{1;1;2;1;1;2;1;1}),"00"),
     ε, SEQUENCE(MAX(INDEX(α,7)/1)),
     MAKEARRAY(ROWS(α),COLUMNS(α),LAMBDA(φ,δ,IFERROR(VLOOKUP(INDEX(α,φ,δ),
     TEXT(SWITCH(φ,1,F2:G4,2,F7:G10,3,F13:G17,4,F20:G21,5,F24:G26,6,F29:G30,7,
     HSTACK(ε,"Plant "&ε),8,F44:G45),"00"),2,0),INDEX(α,φ,δ)&" kilos"))))
```

---

Comment: This is so cool! I will check it thoroughly. Thank you for your help. By the way, If I want to directly add position 9 (number 1 to 9) after 'Plant', instead of lookup for it. How should I add that to the formula you provided? Thank you.

Comment: @user22132557 I understand what you are trying to say, don't think with the existing formula it would work out

Comment: @user22132557 I have an updated for you, the requested option has been amended within the existing formulae

Answer (score 2):

Follow theese examples, you see the pattern and just do the same for all yor secanrios
[image]

[image]

[image]